# Deleted sheet using VBA appears again if the script is used as add in

Tags: excel

I am trying to delete a sheet using macro and also the corresponding text containing the sheet name which was deleted is also to be deleted from the table in column BP simultaneously. Everything is working well. But when the script is used as add in then The sheet which was previously deleted again appears back. I am attaching the code as shown below

Kindly help. What could be the reason for this?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sheetName As String

Dim z As Long
    Dim last As Long

ThisWorkbook.Activate

sheetName = Application.InputBox("Please enter the OSAT Name:", "OSAT", _
, , , , , 2)
    last = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataStorage").Cells(Rows.Count, "BP").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Err.Clear

    On Error Resume Next

    Set xWs = Sheets(sheetName)

    If Err <> 0 Then

        MsgBox "The OSAT '" & sheetName & "'" & "does not exist!", vbInformation, "Excel 10 Tutorial"

        Exit Sub

    Else

        xWs.Delete

        MsgBox "The OSAT '" & sheetName & "'" & "has been deleted!", vbInformation, "Excel 10 Tutorial"
        
    For z = last To 2 Step -1
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataStorage").Cells(z, "BP").Value = sheetName Then
            Sheets("DataStorage").Cells(z, "BP").Delete
        End If
    Next z
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Thisworkbook` references the Add-Ins file. If you close Excel the add-in won't get saved. Therefore the deletion is reset.

You need to add this to the Thisworkbook module

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Thisworkbook.save
End Sub
```

BUT: are you sure you want to save data in an Add-In?

Comment: I added the above piece of code before the deletion script. The deleted sheets are still appearing back if I reopen excel and run the add in

Comment: Did you paste it into the `ThisWorkbook` module (under Microsoft Excel Objects) = the very first module in the tree of your project.

Comment: Yeah, I have pasted the above lines into the ' ThisWorkbook' module, I am getting the error -- Runtime error '1004'. 'This extension cannot be used with the selected file type. Change the file extension in the file name text or select a different file type by changing the Save as type.

Comment: hard to tell: how did you save your addin?